# Update a list element with Lotus Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I am trying to update an element in a list with Lotus Formula.

I thought you would do it like this:

```
x := "0":"0":"0";
x[1] := "1";
```

But when I try to save I get the following error:

```
:= must be immediately preceded by a field or variable name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Lotus Domino Designer 7 Help](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf):

> The subscript operator cannot be used
>   on the left side of an assignment
>   statement. That is, you cannot assign
>   a value to a subscripted element. You
>   must build the complete list and then
>   assign it. For example, if Categories
>   is a 3-element list and you want to
>   assign a new value to element 2:

```
FIELD Categories := Categories[1] : "CatNew" : Categories[3]
```

You can usually get by using @Implode, @Explode, or @Replace. But if you really need it you can do this:

```
REM {FieldName[Index] := NewVal};
Index := 2;
NewVal := "CatNew";

maxIndex := @Elements(FieldName);
PrePart := @If(Index > 1; @Subset(FieldName; Index-1); "");
PostPart := @If(Index < maxIndex; @Subset(FieldName; (Index-maxIndex)); "");

Field FieldName := PrePart : NewVal : PostPart
```

Comment: I've enhanced the Formula to avoid a potential error when Index=1 or Index=maxIndex